# why the second route.MapRoute of the same controller get a Null id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am beginner in ASP.NET MVC.

I have these routes

www.site.com/Afficher/Livre/1

www.site.com/Afficher/Auteur/2

I wrote a One controller with 2 actions. always the second action in the route.MapRoute always get a  null in the id

the controller File : AfficherController

```
    public string Auteurs()
    {
        return "liste des auteurs";
    }

    public string Auteur(int? idAuteur)
    {
        return "liste des livres de l'auteur "+idAuteur+" sont :";
    }

    public string Livre(int idlivre)
    {
        return "details du livre " + idlivre + " est : ";
    }
```

the routing file

```
  routes.MapRoute(
     name: "afficherLivre",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{idlivre}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Afficher", action = "Livre", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "AfficherAuteur",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{idAuteur}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Afficher", action = "Auteur", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Afficher", action = "Auteurs", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please would you take care when asking questions that your question is clear and easy to understand. This one is not so you should edit it. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You route definitions make no sense - all 3 routes are identical - they accept between 0 and 3 segments, and any url will match the first one and `../Afficher/Auteur/2` will pass `2` as a value to a parameter named `idlivre` - but you do not have a parameter named `idlivre` in the `Auteur` method. - and using `id = UrlParameter.Optional` makes no sense since you do not even have a parameter named `id`

Comment: If you want specific routes then the first should be `url: "Afficher/Livre/{idlivre}",` with `idlivre = UrlParameter.Optional` and the 2nd  `url: "Afficher/Auteur/{idAuteur}",`with `idAuteur = UrlParameter.Optional` although what would be the point. Just make the parameters in your methods `id` and delete the first 2 routes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a parameter through the url, its name should be the same in three places in your ASP.NET code: in `url` and `defaults` parameters of `MapRoute` and also in action parameter. You changed `url` and action parameter, but forgot to replace `id` with `idAuteur` in `defaults` parameter. Your code should work if you'll do so.

But what is more important, it looks like you are creating own MapRoute for every action. You don't have to. Just leave MapRoute with name `Default` and change parameter names to `id` in actions `Auteur` and `Livre`.

Good luck!